# Format preserving encryption

Tags: format-preserving

Can format preserving encryption be used for any other applications than Credit card, pan card or social security numbers?

If, could you provide a few examples for my further research on the topic?

Comment: Yes. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Can you mention a few, please?

Comment: [honey encryption](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rist/papers/HoneyEncryptionpre.pdf), low-bandwith channels, sampling distinct integers from a range ​ ​

Comment: ofcourse yes , check answers for other questions on same topic, it is well covered here

Comment: @RickyDemer Only a reminder: *“Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.”* After all, you’ve got a valid answer right there…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. ​ ​ Low-bandwidth channels and

[sampling distinct integers from a range] are examples of that.

Contrary to my comment, I now believe that honey encryption is not quite an example of that.